# How to uninstall ChromeOS and install Ubuntu on a chromebook

Tags: chromebook

Ive looked at many similar questions but none of them work.

Using Crouton on the Chromebook worked for a while but not any more. I have to reinstall Crouton every time I want to use Ubuntu so now I want to make the entire system work right off of Ubuntu without running ChromeOS.

I am using the Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga 11e Chromebook. I heard you have to take out some screw but I do not see where that would do anything. I've taken this thing apart many times but I did not see this red screw.

Can you tell me in detail where the screw is and tell me the rest of the steps needed to boot Ubuntu as the OS. I already have Ubuntu 16.04 on a USB drive that I know works because I've used it many times.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure on that particular model of chromebook. I just went through the hassle of uninstalling chromeOS from my Asus c202s. Things you should provide if you want better help: Model number of chromebook and CPU Architecture. There are plenty of ways to wipe chromeOS from your machine. Each machine is unique and requires a little different process. But here is a good start for you. You need to look up how to remove the "jumper screw". But you can also just look at the mobo, you should see a screw/ screwhole on the mobo with two copper semi circles on either side of the screw. This is the jumper, the screw head shorts the two copper pads. After you have disabled write protection, you will need to go into dev mode. Once in dev mode I would go this route; install a new bios, preferably a UEFI bios but if you cannot find one that works with your machine then you can try looking for a Legacy bios.

[UEFI bios](https://mrchromebox.tech/#fwscript)

[Legacy bios](https://johnlewis.ie/custom-chromebook-firmware/rom-download/)

After your new bios is installed you can then boot from USB.

Don't Brick, Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Step one: Plug in your USB.
Step two: There should be a button you can use during startup to open BIOS. Open BIOS.
Step three: Go through the settings, somewhere there should be startup order. Set your USB to top priority.
Step four: Ubuntu should boot up. Go to the desktop and click on the install icon.
Step five: Follow the install process.
I hope this helps, it's my first time using this to answer.

Comment: This is a Chromebook, not a normal PC. Unfortunately, there is no normal BIOS menu by default.